# Eloquent to combine data from 2 x tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Table Structure:

```
games

id | name

awards

id | award name | game_id (fk)
```

Relationships

A game can have many awards.
An award has one game.

```
class Games extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function awards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('award');
    }
}
```

I need to get all the games out of my database. I do this using:

```
Game::all();
```

I then need to get all of the games out of my database but include data from the awards table.

I want to have an array which I can loop through to output the games, and if the game has an award - output this also.

What would be the correct eloquent statement?

Comment: You're inconsistent with ```Games/Game```. Fix that! What about ```Games::with('awards')->get()```?

Comment: Are you using namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel's relations are brilliant for this kind of thing. Everything you have so far is on the correct path.

```
// Controller
public function index()
{
    $games = Game::all();

    return view('games.index', compact('games'));
}

// View
@foreach($games as $game)

    {{ $game->name }}

    @if(count($game->awards) > 0)
        // Game has some awards, lets loop through them

        @foreach($game->awards as $award)
            {{ $award->name }}
        @endforeach        

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Using the relation you've setup in your `Game` model you can instantly access the related data from other tables. Now each time you call `$game->awards` it will query the database, however using Laravel's Eager Loading you can pull all this information out at the same time rather than on demand.

```
// Controller
public function index()
{
    $games = Game::with('awards')->get();

    return view('games.index', compact('games'));
}
```

and by doing the exact same thing in the view you're no longer running a new query each time you want to get a games awards as they've already be fetched from the database. More on eager loading here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Great answer! Just a quick question - what does compact do?

Comment: `compact` is an array builder which uses the key names from a form input as values and and keys for a new array. Its a shorter and syntactical way of building up an array in PHP these days ;)